TinyMCE is not showing my content html from Bubble Data Base
help if possible.
I use tinyMCE for the system admin area to insert content. The same content is saved in html in the database. Naturally I want to display the content on the front, I can get all the content except videos. When they're from YouTube, okay, they appear. But when they are from Panda Video it doesn't appear on the front.
On the front of the system I display the html with the bubble html element.
Have you been through this? Do you have any guidance?
I'm try to create content with TinyMCE and show this content in an HTML element of Bubble.io project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
